# How to jump to file explorer in VS Code?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Using the VIM extension for VS Code is there a key command to jump to the explorer pane and then back to the work window?

I cannot find anything in the docs.

I'm hoping there is something like my Control+N binding for NERDTree which lets me open the file viewer, pick a file and then close it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I am not familiar with NERDTree, but I think  `Ctrl+Shift+e` does what you are asking in vs code. Alternatively  `Ctrl+p` may be an alternative? You could look at
[linux keyboard shortcut for more reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf).

The link is also available in Help > Keyboard Shortcut Reference

**EDIT:** I'm adding the equivalent shortcut for Mac OS since it's different layout. However, I don't use Mac OS.. So I add this without being able to confirm :

`Shift+Command+E`
[Mac OS Keyboard shortcut for VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf)

Windows keyboard shortcuts are very similar to linux ones. So, I'll just include the link to windows shortcuts doc here. [Windows Keyboard shortcut for VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf)

Comment: I have a similar question. But this is not exactly what I want. I can use the Cmd+Shift+e to open and close the tree but I can't really go up and down with `jk`. Is there anyway to do that in vscode vim?

Comment: @Yathi Since you mentioned Cmd key, I assume you're using Mac OS and/or keyboard. I'm not very familiar with the interaction there. But, when I looked at the display shortcut keys in the Mac version it did say ` shift+cmd+e` for toggle focus. Which should allow you to then use up/dwn arrows to navigate it. But, I don't have a Mac to verify the interaction. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, the shortcut does take me to the file tree. And I can go up and down using the arrow keys. But if I press `Enter` it opens the rename window and doesn't open the file. Anyway, I now have an idea on how I can probably remap some keys to achieve what I want. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Yathi I'm able to navigate files in vscode tree but yes I also still have no idea how to change `Enter` behavior. I need it to open a file instead of renaming it

Comment: You don't need to press Enter. Just use `L` to open the file and change the focus.

Comment: Refer to this StackOverflow question for the file explorer keyboard shortcut key. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48203523/how-to-create-file-in-current-explorer-directory-in-vs-code-using-only-keys

Answer (score 18):

Just my two cents:

If you are using the [Vim](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim) extension for VS code you can add this to your settings.json file:

```
"vim.normalModeKeyBindings": [
  {
    "before" : ["<leader>","a"],
    "commands" : [
      "workbench.view.explorer"
    ]
  }
]
```

The exemple above uses `<leader> + a` while in normal mode to display the file explorer  where you can navigate the file list with j and k. Pressing ENTER will open the file under the cursor and close the file list.

To set up a leader key just add in your settings.json:

```
"vim.leader" : "," ,
```

Comment: Thanks this helped. Is there any setting to auto close explorer once file is opened.

Comment: @NatwarSingh I no longer use VSCode so I'm not sure.

Comment: It would be so nice to keep old behaviour where "enter" wouldn't open the file so you can "/" search and go to the next hit. This used to work at some point.

Comment: This tip was great for me!  I'm using Linux, and the standard ctrl+shift+e shortcut doesn't work for some reason, so remapping this works for me (and is more vim-like)!

Answer (score 9):

Also if you are using the `vim` extension for VS code you can edit `settings.json` with :

```
    "vim.handleKeys": {
        "<C-p>": false,
    }
}
```

to bring back the native VSCode file search with `Ctrl+p`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Santiago's comment, you're able to open a file in a new tab from the explorer (Cmd + Shift + E) with Ctrl + Enter for MacOS.  I'm not sure about Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go to a file with VIM in VSCode:

Enter Normal Mode (Esc)

Place cursor over file you want to jump to, e.g. between the quotes - "../models/postMessage.js";

Press lowercase gd - Go to definition

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the file faster by typing the file name and you don't want to lose your Vim normal Ctrl+P functionality, you could add this to your `settings.json` to map the VSCode Quick Open action to `leader + p`.

```
  "vim.normalModeKeyBindings": [
    {
        "before": ["<leader>", "p"],
        "commands": ["workbench.action.quickOpen"]
    },
```